# maximal subset of integers that are not evenly divisible by k

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a practice problem I am solving:

Given a set S of  distinct integers, print the size of a maximal subset S' of S where the sum of any 2 numbers in S' are not evenly divisible by k.

My approach was to limit the problem to the subset `S[0...i]` where 0 < i <= n-1 and determine the length of the maximal subset for that subproblem, then extend the subproblem by 1. I know there is a different approach to this problem but I am confused why my solution does not work.

ex) for n = 10, k = 5, and `S` = `[770528134, 663501748, 384261537, 800309024, 103668401, 538539662, 385488901, 101262949, 557792122, 46058493]`

```
dp = [0 for _ in range(n)]
dp[0] = 1
for i in range(1, n):
    flag = 0
    for j in range(i):
        if s[j] == "#":
            pass
        elif (not s[j] == "#") and (s[j] + s[i])%k==0:
            dp[i] = dp[i-1]
            flag = 1
            s[i] = "#"
            break
    if not flag == 1:
        dp[i] = dp[i-1] + 1
print dp[-1]
```

The output should be `6` but my function prints `5`. What I try to do is iterate from `j=0` to `i` and check if for any `j` < `i` if `(s[j] + s[i])%k==0`. If so, then considering `s[i]` in S' would be erroneous so instead mark `s[i]` with a `#` to indicate it is not in S'.

Comment: When you say `any 2 numbers in S'` in the problem statement, do you mean any 2 *distinct* numbers? Or, in your example where `k=5`, would `5` always be excluded since 5+5 is evenly divisible by 5?

Comment: any two distinct numbers. `5` is not in S so it wouldn't be S`. any two numbers in `S` are distinct

Comment: So you are saying that if 5 were in S it could also be in S'? I know this question does not affect your particular example, but I assume you want code that works for all sets.

Comment: If `5` were in `S`, there would be no other `5` in `S`. All numbers in S are distinct.

Comment: There is some miscommunication here. In the example k=5, S=[1,2,5], would the answer be S'=[1,2] or S'=[1,2,5]? (Note that 5+5 is divisible by k and 5 is in S.)

Answer (score 2):

Your lack of comments and explanatory names makes your code very hard to follow, so I do not understand it. (Your example using a list when you talk of sets, and the use of both `s` and `S` for your "set", do not help.) However, the basic idea of your algorithm is flawed: this problem for a given set cannot be solved by extending the solution for a proper subset.

For example, take `k=3`, set `S=[1,4,2,5,8]`. For the first three elements `[1,4,2]`, the solution is `[1,4]`. For the first four elements `[1,4,2,5]`, the solution is either `[1,4]` or `[2,5]`. For the entire set, the solution is `[2,5,8]`. You see there is no "path" from the solution from the first three elements through the first five: you need to "restart" at either the first four or the entire set.

A solution that does work partitions the entire set S into equivalence classes where the elements in each class have the same remainder when divided by k. Examining these equivalence classes gives the final result. Let me know if you need more details. Note that you will need to decide clearly if `any 2 numbers in S'` means any 2 *distinct* numbers in S': this changes what you do at one or two of the equivalence classes.

Comment: A very fine answer in several respects!